Cloudbuild unable to download Public github repo as a module
Issue - We are trying to deploy gke in our environment using Google's public modules but facing an issue.
This is how we're calling Google's module to create cluster inside our Terrform hosted in client's environment Github.
cluster.tf has below code
module "gke_cluster" {
  source = "terraform-google-modules/kubernetes-engine/google//modules/beta-autopilot-public-cluster"
  version                         = "~> 30.0"
.
.
.}

inside cloudbuild.yaml we have below code
In cloudbuild.yaml file we have,
steps:
      - name: "hashicorp/terraform"
        entrypoint: sh
        args:
          - '-c'
          - |
            terraform init && terraform plan
options:
       logging: CLOUD_LOGGING_ONLY

Also, we have a Cloudbuild trigger created for this repo and it points to above yaml file on trigger.
But, everytime we run this build in Git, it fails with below errors.

failed to download module..
could not download module from
https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/kubernetes-engine/google//modules/beta-autopilot-public-cluster
/usr/bin/git exited with 1: git: 'credential-gcloud.sh' is not a git
Could not read username for https://github.com. No such device or
address..

All these errors do get logged in same build, we tried changing yaml file with different variations but it's same result.
Note: Cloudbuild trigger is associated with a service account which has owner permission so its permission shouldn't be an issue.
Region - us-central1
Also, when we tried cluster.tf to below
module "gke_cluster" {
  source = "git@github.com:terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-kubernetes-engine.git/google//modules/beta-autopilot-public-cluster"

I am getting below error

Host key verification failed, could not read from remote repository,
make sure you've the correct access rights and the repository exists.

I am not sure how to handle this as I assume that accessing a public repo shouldn't need any authentication.
Please advise.

Please format your question to display the build step correctly. Include enough so that we can reproduce your problem.

Sure @JohnHanley- I have added more details now, also worked on formatting the content/text.
